# Put someone out

Tags: meaning

When we talk about a horse what it could mean.

> I'm not going to race him. I'm going to put him out to stud.

I would guess that put out means here exactly

> To publish something or make it publicly available

**[link](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+out)**/meaning_6

Is that true?

Comment: *[Put out/retire to stud](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/put-out-retire-to-stud)* is a phrase, meaning "to keep a male animal that no longer works for breeding".

Comment: The term has been used of bitches too (https://books.google.com/books?id=63s9AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA309&dq=%22put+out+to+stud%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qVmFVa3DGcfk-AHL9rb4BA&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22put%20out%20to%20stud%22&f=false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Put out" is remarkably versatile.

1. It can have a literal meaning.  "**Put out** the cat for the night."  And the related figurative usage:  "He **put out** feelers to see if anyone would offer him a job."
2. To inconvenience:  "Would it **put** you **out** if I borrowed your car?"
3. To be annoyed:  "It really **puts** me **out** that he keeps asking to borrow my car.
4. Baseball term of art:  "He tried to turn a single into a double, but he was **put out** at second."
5. Render unconscious:  "Don't worry about the operation.  They'll **put** you **out** with anesthesia and you won't feel a thing."
6. Of anything burning, to extinguish. A fire, a cigaret.
7. Vulgar slang:  of a woman, agree to have sex.
8. Of a newspaper, to publish.

   For publish or make publicly known (particularly rumors), you may be thinking of "put it about."

Comment: So, I was right about the meaning in my case?

Comment: @DmitryBundin No, "put out to stud" means to make available for breeding.  To make something publicly available, you "put that something about."

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the phrasal *put out* here.

> I'm not going to race him. I'm going to put him out to stud.

- *put* is the verb
- *him* is the direct object
- *out* is an adverb (modifying *put*)

[***put***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/put) as used means:

> 3) to cause to be in a certain position or place; place; set   ⇒ *"put the box here"*

basically sending the horse to a stud farm.

Comment: See, I heard that usage in the Godfather movie. That's why I think I can use it that way.

Comment: Are you asking if *putting a horse out to stud* means "making the horse *publicly available* for the purpose of breeding"?